# UndefinedTable: relation table does not exist when using `copy_from` method

Tags: python, postgresql, copy, psycopg2

I am trying to write a script that creates a new table in my Postgres database and copies an existing csv file to that table using the psycopg2 library. To be clear, I am strictly trying to do this with `psycopg2`, not using other methods like `psql.exe` or `ogr2ogr.` So far, I can connect, create the table, and do a test query of an existing table. *Note: this database has multiple schemas. I created one called 'test' to place my tables.

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import psycopg2
from os import path
from datetime import datetime

csv_file = r"C:\Projects\csv_report_to_sql\test\csv_report.csv"

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb', user='postgres', password='mypassword', host='www.mydbserver.com', port='5432', sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE test.new_table
    (
        region TEXT,
        state TEXT,
        tier TEXT,
        v_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_total DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_total DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
""")
conn.commit()
```

I can now see the table under my `test` schema, but to test it in the script, I can run :

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test.new_table')
one = cur.fetchone()
print(one)
```

and it returns "None", which it correct as its an empty table. Now, I want to copy my csv file data to this new table. I am new to `psycopg2` but from this [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/loading-data-into-postgres/), I am assuming I have to make a new connection as the old one get closed.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb', user='postgres', password='mypassword', host='www.mydbserver.com', port='5432', sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    next(f) # Skip the header row.
    cur.copy_from(f, 'test.new_table', sep=',')

conn.commit()
```

When I run the above, I get the following error:

> UndefinedTable: relation "new_table" does not exist

I can clearly see that the table exists, so what am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You should be able to reuse your `conn`. If it's not open in `with psycopg2.connect(...) as conn:` it won't automatically close. That way you'll be sure you're interacting with the same database in both parts of the code. It's also a good practice to reuse your connections because constant opening and closing is needlessly expensive.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Disregard that part.; I just assumed it closed after commit().

Comment: I cannot replicate.  Try doing it all under one connection and see what happens? The only way I can see this happening is with two different database sessions where the one creating the table did not commit so the other one does not see the table.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was a weird fix but I assume it may have something to do with running it in separate cells in the Jupyter Notebook. Basically, I just combined everything together (removing the second connection as suggested) in one cell and it ran correctly. Assume there would be no issue with running it in a standalone script.

```
import os
import sys
import psycopg2
import csv

csv_file = r"C:\Projects\csv_report_to_sql\test\csv_report.csv"

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb', user='postgres', password='mypassword', 
host='www.mydbserver.com', port='5432', sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE test.new_table
    (
        region TEXT,
        state TEXT,
        tier TEXT,
        v_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
        v_total DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_detailed DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_approx DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_unmapped DOUBLE PRECISION,
        a_total DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
""")
conn.commit()
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    next(f) # Skip the header row.
    cur.copy_from(f, 'test.new_table', sep=',')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```